# draw two different arrows (from arrows library)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I did'n find a way to draw two different arrows (from the arrows tikz library) between two nodes ... For example, -triangle 45 at one extremity and -open triangle 90 at the other extremity. Any idea about how to do that ?

Answer (score 9):

Simply place the specifications at either side of the `-`: `open triangle 90-triangle 45`, as in:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) {A};
\node (b) at (2,0) {B};
\draw[open triangle 90-triangle 45] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows at either end]

Comment: Hum ... thanks ! and sorry for this naive question.

Comment: @user7137: No need to apologise!  That's what this site is for: things that are easy for one are tricky for another.